# Getting values from XML in SSIS

Tags: xml, ssis

I have data in XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<APIDATA xmlns="api-com">
<ORDER EngineID="1" OrderID="66"></ORDER>
<ORDER EngineID="2" OrderID="67"></ORDER>
</APIDATA>
```

In SSIS control flow, i would like to loop on the orders. I need the two IDs form the order elements for later use. I use a Foreach loop component, with Foreach NodeList Enumerator.

```
Enumeration type: NodeText
OuterXpathString: //@EngineID | //@OrderID
```

Then on variable mappings I use two string variables with index 0 and 1, to get the two IDs. To my woe, the variable values are not what I expect, they are inverted in some way. They appear as the following:

```
loop sequence 1: variable1 = 1, variable2 = 2
loop sequence 2: variable1 = 66, variable2 = 67
```

This is incorrect, as I would like to execute tasks in a loop, using the IDs of a single ORDER element. (So I would like to get loop sequence 1: variable1 = 1, variable2 = 66.) How can I achieve this? Is something fundamentally wrong with my xpath?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm running your example under SSIS 2012 and got different results: four iterations, 1: V1==V2==1; 2: V1==V2==66; 3: V1==V2==2; 4: V1==V2==67;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
EnumerationType:  ElementCollection
OuterXPathString: //*[name() = 'ORDER']
InnerElementType: NodeText
InnerXPathString: @*
```

Variables set exactly as you.

In my SSIS 2012 it works, but as I've written in question comment I've got different results running your example than you. So it's possible that your result would be different too.

Generally OuterXPathString is complicated due to namespace in your xml (more info: [XMLNS breaks XPath referencing](http://j.mp/RhljVQ)), without xmlns at APIDATA element it would be: `//ORDER`.